# PySide2, how to stretch the QTableWidget to fit Window witdh?

Tags: python, qt, width, pyside, qtablewidget

I am trying to have a QTableWidget stretch horizontaly to fit the window width but I can't find how to do it. I am new to Qt.

The floowing code snippet and image show that, on resizing horizontaly the program window, the QLineEdit stretches to fit the window width but the QTableWidget doesn't.

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QTableWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QWidget()
win.setWindowTitle('test')
win.setMinimumWidth(400)

layV1 = QVBoxLayout()
win.setLayout(layV1)

entry = QLineEdit(win)
entry.setPlaceholderText('test entry widget')
layV1.addWidget(entry)

table = QTableWidget(win)
table.setRowCount(10)
table.setColumnCount(5)
layV1.addWidget(table)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to stretch the last section :

```
table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

If you want to stretch a specific column, you need to use a QHeaderView.
Quick example with your code.

```
headerView = QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, table)
table.setHorizontalHeader(headerView)
headerView.setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
headerView.setSectionsClickable(True)
```

Just replace 2 by the desired column to stretch!

Comment: Actually this serves my use case better than what I asked, so thank you for added comments about stretching a particular column. But, for the sake of completeness, is there a way to get all the columns stretch together to fit the unused space ?

Comment: Hi @NicolaMingotti ! You can do that by duplicate this line : headerView.setSectionResizeMode(COLUMN, QHeaderView.Stretch) and put another column. In your example, you can duplicate this line 5 times. I don't know if there is another better solution.

Comment: Hi @AlexLaur, confirmed working. thank you. I mark the thing solved. bye.